# How to correctly use kustomize replacements in bases (replacing old vars feature)?

Tags: kubernetes, variables, replace, yaml, kustomize

I'm trying to replace the deprecated "vars" with "replacements". However I can't get it to work as desired.

I have the following example code, which works:

resource.yaml:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: FooBar
metadata:
  labels:
    my.label.io/name: NAME_PLACEHOLDER
  name: NAME_PLACEHOLDER
  namespace: NAMESPACE_PLACEHOLDER
spec:
  foo: bar
```

kustomization.yaml:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- resource.yaml

replacements:
- source:
    fieldPath: metadata.name
    kind: FooBar
    name: NAME_PLACEHOLDER
  targets:
  - fieldPaths:
    - metadata.labels.[my.label.io/name]
    select:
      kind: FooBar
      name: NAME_PLACEHOLDER

namespace: my-final-namespace
patches:
- target:
    kind: FooBar
    name: NAME_PLACEHOLDER
  patch: |-
    - op: replace
      path: /metadata/name
      value: my-final-name
```

Output of `kubectl kustomize .` is as intended:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: FooBar
metadata:
  labels:
    my.label.io/name: my-final-name
  name: my-final-name
  namespace: my-final-namespace
spec:
  foo: bar
```

If I now separate this into base and overlay, it doesn't work anymore.

Base kustomization.yaml:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- resource.yaml

replacements:
- source:
    fieldPath: metadata.name
    kind: FooBar
    name: NAME_PLACEHOLDER
  targets:
  - fieldPaths:
    - metadata.labels.[my.label.io/name]
    select:
      kind: FooBar
      name: NAME_PLACEHOLDER
```

Overlay kustomization.yaml:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- ../base/

namespace: my-final-namespace
patches:
- target:
    kind: FooBar
    name: NAME_PLACEHOLDER
  patch: |-
    - op: replace
      path: /metadata/name
      value: my-final-name
```

`kubectl kustomize .` output:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: FooBar
metadata:
  labels:
    my.label.io/name: NAME_PLACEHOLDER
  name: my-final-name
  namespace: my-final-namespace
spec:
  foo: bar
```

The same principle worked as intended while using "vars", but since they are deprecated: How would you do this now?

Of course this is a simplified example, but in reality I would have tons of overlays with the exact same replaces (many of them), which I would not like to duplicate the code for.

So is there a way to keep doing that in the base and in overlay only patch a single occurrence of a value?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've already followed the formatting reference for "[replacements](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/replacements/)", you might want to check your format with regards to "patches" you can see in this [link](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/patches/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).